# Pandas rolling window with less than or equal to

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is classified based on three dimensions:

```
>>> df
   a  b  c  d
0  a  b  c  1
1  a  e  x  2
2  a  f  e  3
```

when I do a rolling of metric d by the following command:

```
>>> df.d.rolling(window = 3).mean()
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    2.0
Name: d, dtype: float64
```

but what I actually want is to perform a rolling <= given number, in a way that if for the first entry the result is the same number itself and then from the second entry it rolls for the window size of 1 and for third it rolls for the window size of 2 and from 3 onwards it rolls the running average of 3 previous windows.

So the result I am expecting is:

for the dataframe:

```
>>> df
   a  b  c  d
0  a  b  c  1
1  a  e  x  2
2  a  f  e  3

>>> df.d.rolling(window = 3).mean()
0    1 #Since this is the first one and so average of the first number is equal to number itself.
1    1.5 # Average of 1 and 2 as rolling criteria is <= 3
2    2.0 # Since here we have 3 elements so from here on it follows the general trend.
Name: d, dtype: float64
```

Is it possible to roll this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to roll using the following command:

```
>>> df.d.rolling(min_periods = 1, window = 3).mean()
0    1.0
1    1.5
2    2.0
Name: d, dtype: float64
```

with the help of `min_periods` one can specify the rolling window minimum config count.